# MethodBase.Invoke with Convert.ChangeType object result

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.Int16");
object number = Convert.ChangeType("-9", type); //m_value = 3096
MethodInfo method = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Abs", new[] { type });
object resultWithoutCast = method.Invoke(null, new[] { number }); //m_value = 3096
var resultWithCast = (Int16)resultWithoutCast; //9
```

I'm not sure I know what "m_value" is.  My guess is a memory location?  What I'm trying to accomplish here is to get the value 9 from resultWithoutCast object, dynamically, without having to cast to Int16.

Thoughts?

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType("-9", Type.GetType("System.Int16"))` is indeed `-9` and not `3096`. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fl568A). It's unclear what all of the above is supposed to accomplish; you may have oversimplified the example. How do you propose to "get" the value? As what would you like to store it -- how are you going to process it? You get back a boxed value; you cannot store it in a statically typed location without casting, and you do not need to cast to store it in a dynamically typed location.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the reply.  I went for a walk and the solution came to me... I just needed to .ToString() the object to get the resulting value back, no cast required.  I'm still unsure what object.m_value is.  I've Googled it and couldn't find anything substantial.

Comment: It's a fake. `System.Int16` is defined as [a struct with an `m_value` member](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int16.cs#L17), but that's mostly a placeholder to make reflection work. Internally primitive types are treated specially by the JIT, but the debugger doesn't really know that.

Comment: Also, note that for this very particular sequence of operations, the whole thing would be much more easily implemented as `Regex.Replace("-9", "^-", "")` (remove the initial minus, if present -- a string-based implementation of taking the absolute value). Probably not applicable to your scenario, but just putting it out there. :-)

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.  Still not sure I fully understand what m_value is.  The comment in the code indicates something about "binary serialization"?  I don't see it set anywhere in the code.  Odd.  Yeah my example IS oversimplified.  The code will eventually apply to many other Math methods, each with their own inputs and outputs.

Comment: It is not set anywhere because `System.Int16` (the structure) is more or less a fake type to keep up the illusion that everything in .NET is an object. In reality, `Int16` values have native support in the runtime and this type is never actually used (except in special cases, like binary serialization). Rather than a structure with an `m_value` member, an `Int16` is simply treated as two bytes in memory (or a register) by the runtime at nearly all times. I don't actually know the layout of a boxed `int16` in memory, but it's probably not this struct, so the debugger decodes the value wrong.